# How to output a number over 9 in IJVM?

Tags: assembly, ascii, addition, ijvm, mic-1

i have searched a lot, but unsuccessful. Maybe you can help me, give some advice or source where i can find the answer. I can not understand how to output a number if it is more than 9 in IJVM architecture with MIC-1 simulator, I have a simple 2 number addition code.

```
.main
BIPUSH 0x35// PUSH 5
BIPUSH 0x33 // PUSH 3
IADD // PUSH sum(5,3)
DUP
BIPUSH 0x30 // PUSH 0
ISUB // subtract 0
OUT 
.end-main
```

Comment: repeated modulo and division by 10 to get the low digit, same as in any other language / CPU architecture.

Comment: can you give me example?

Comment: C and x86 asm: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13166064/how-do-i-print-an-integer-in-assembly-level-programming-without-printf-from-the/46301894#46301894